# Software algorithm practice-Binary Search

Tags: algorithm

I am new to algorithm. found this question and got stuck half of my day. My guess of times of key comparison is T(n)=2n-2. Ie O(n) Any advice? Appreciate.

Given a sorted array of n elements, A[0..n − 1], and a constant C. We want to determine if there
is a pair of elements A[i] and A[j], i != j, such that A[i] + A[j] = C. (We want a Boolean function
which returns a TRUE/FALSE answer.)
(a) Outline how this problem may be solved by using the binary-search algorithm, BS(A, lef t, right, key).
(Do not give the code for BS. It is a given function, which you call.) Analyze the time complexity of this approach.
(b) Descrive a more efficient O(n) algorithm to solve this problem. Give the pseudo-code. Explain how the algorithm works, and provide a numerical illustration.

Comment: You should format this correctly. What is T(n)? for (a): the binary search will tell you for a specific number, if it is in the list. Try to figure out how to use that. Hint: you will need to iterate through the entire list once.

Answer (score 0):

a) You could iterate through all of the elements in the array (in O(n) time) and call binary search to find the number C - A[i] in the same array (in O(log n) time. If such a number exists, the two numbers would sum to C. The total running time of this operation is O(n log n)

b) You could use a set to store all of the values in the array as you iterate through the array and then for each number you come across, you check to see if the set contains the number C-A[i]. You then add the number A[i] to the set. Checking to see if a set contains a number is O(1) (assuming it's a hashset), and iterating through the array is O(n), giving a final runtime of O(n).

Pseudocode:

```
set S to a new set
for i in list A:
    if S contains C-A[i]:
        return true
    add A[i] to set
 return false
```

EDIT: I see you are using T(n). In the programming world, everybody uses O(n), which is a crucial subject to understand if you want to become proficient in algorithms. I suggest you learn it before you progress to anything else.

Comment: for part b, there is no need to increase memory usage... you don't need the set.

Comment: There's no other way to do it in O(n) time. It's a time-space tradeoff. With today's memory capabilities, runtime is infinitely more valuable than memory.

Comment: You mean.. you don't know any other way to do it in O(n).  There certainly is a way to do it in O(n) time and O(1) space.  as a matter of fact, it's even posted as an answer in a comment below this question.

Comment: Sorry--I overlooked the fact that it was sorted in implementing part b... In that case, the solution provided in the comment would be more space-efficient. Should I revise my solution or leave it as is?

Comment: Thank you for correcting me , actually I wanted use T(n) as times of comparison. sorry I did not make myself clear

Comment: This should be O(n):
Pseudocode:
boolean match(A, left,right, C){
if(left >= right) return false;
if(a[left]+A[right]==C) return true;
else if(a[left]+A[right]>C) return match(A,left,right-1,C);
else if(a[left]+A[right]>C) return match(A,left+1,right,C);
}